# How does ANSI C-Quoting in Herestrings work?

Tags: bash, heredoc, ansi-c, parameter-expansion, herestring

Why is this not working?

```sh
bla="
multi

line

string
"
cat -A <<EOF
${bla//\$'\n'/\\\$'\n'}
EOF
```

this works:

```sh
cat -A <<EOF
$(cat <<<${bla//$'\n'/\\$'\n'})
EOF
```

as noted in a comment this also works:

```sh
newline=$'\n'
cat -A <<EOF
${bla//$newline/\\$newline}
EOF
```

Expected:

```
\$
multi\$
\$
line\$
\$
string\$
```

I guess it has something to do with Quoting and how *heredocs* work.
But as `set -x` is not working for *parameter expansion* debugging, i could not figue it out.

A link to where it is explained in the *GNU Bash Reference Manual* would also help.

**Note:** The *$* in *Expected:* are from *cat -A* option and stand for the newline *\n* character.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem with Bash 5.1.16. I think I remember a similar question on this forum. As a workaround, use a variable for the newline.

Comment: I think you placed one more backslash in the first example (before both of the `$`), which makes people think that's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to remove some of the `\` in the parameter expansion.

That is, it should read `${bla//$'\n'\$$'\n'}`.

```
$ bla="
multi
line
string
"
$ printf "%q\n" "$bla"
$'\nmulti\nline\nstring\n'
$ gcat -A <<EOF
${bla//$'\n'/\$$'\n'}
EOF
$
multi$
line$
string$
$
```

What I have adds a `$` at the end of each line.

```
$ bla="
multi
line
string
"
$ printf "%q" "$bla"
$'\nmulti\nline\nstring\n'
$ printf "%s" "${bla//$'\n'/\$$'\n'}"
$
multi$
line$
string$
$ printf "%q" "${bla//$'\n'/\$$'\n'}"
$'$\nmulti$\nline$\nstring$\n'
```

I am using

```
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
5.1.16(1)-release
```

- See [section 3.6.6](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents) in the Bash manual for info about "here documents".
- See [section 3.5.3](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) for parameter expansion.
- See [section 3.1.2.4](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) for ANSI-C quoting.

Comment: `Expected:` op wants to add \ to end of every line. `${bla//$'\n'/\$$'\n'}` does not work on my bash. `$` on the end are the result of `-A` option. Try `${bla//$'\n'/abc}`

Comment: thx for the links

Comment: Were you able to get it working as you want? I'd be happy to help if you want it.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is this not working?

Apparently because Bash has longstanding behavioral inconsistencies around ANSI-C quoting.

[Its documentation for ANSI-C quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) does not make any contextual exceptions.

[Its documentation for heredocs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents) does not make any special provision that seems relevant:

> If [the delimiter word] is unquoted, all lines of the here-document are subjected to
> parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion,
> the character sequence `\newline` is ignored, and ‘\’ must be used to
> quote the characters ‘\’, ‘$’, and ‘`’.

Inasmuch as I take that last sentence to have an implied "in order to remove their special significance", I see nothing there or in the description of parameter expansion to suggest that parameter expansion works differently in a heredoc than it works elsewhere.

But demonstrably, it does.  Specifically, ANSI-C quoted strings are recognized in parameter expansions outside of heredocs, but not in lexically the same parameter expansions inside heredocs.  This seems to affect *all* forms of parameter expansion that involve text other than the parameter name as part of the expansion, and it does not depend on the use of any of the C-style escape sequences.  Examples:

```sh
$ ex1=abcdef
$ cat <<<${ex1#*$'b'}
cdef
$ cat <<EOF
${ex1#*$'b'}
EOF
abcdef
```

```
ex2=a\$bcdef
$ cat <<<${ex2%$'b'*}
a$
$ cat <<EOF
${ex2%$'b'*}
${ex2/$'b'/X}
EOF
a
aXcdef
```

The actual behavior seems to be that the `$` introducing the C-style quote is taken as a literal character, but the single quotes are interpreted according to their ordinary role as quote characters.  The simplest workaround seems to be to assign the ANSI-C-quoted text to a variable:

```
var=$'b'
$ cat <<EOF
${ex1/${var}/X}
EOF
aXcdef
```

I was first inclined to guess that this behavioral difference is related to ANSI-C quoting not being recognized directly in the body of a heredoc. However, neither is quoting with single- or double-quotes recognized directly in heredocs, yet those quoting forms are still recognized inside parameter expansions embedded in heredocs.  I'm having a hard time seeing why it should not be considered a bug that some parameter expansions are interpreted differently inside heredocs than they are outside.